# How to know how many users install my iOS app after receiving Facebook invitation

Tags: ios, facebook

I would like to track Facebook invitations but I don't know if it's possible.

How many users install my iOS app after receiving a Facebook Invitation?

Thanks.

Comment: This question seems really broad to me. Is there any way to pass along a tracking ID with the invitation URL? Or when your new users log in for the first time, can they authenticate via Facebook?

Comment: Actually I just want to know how many users installed my app after receiving a Facebook invitation from a friend.

Comment: I need the Ratio Invitations/Installations